# Bot no longer responding in Teams chat

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I've built a C# bot which has been working very well, but on Friday it stopped responding completely. I still get a 'bot is typing' message for a while then it goes away with no reply.

The bot works as expected in the Azure test chat, and also replies in my Teams group but not in private chat.

I've tried changing the messaging endpoint, adding the skype channel then removing it, removing the Teams channel and re-adding it, re built the code but nothing makes a difference.

Bot is typing but doesn't reply
[image: Bot is typing but doesn't reply]

Bot replies in Teams group
[image: Bot replies in Teams group]

Comment: Can you please provide bot id so that we could investigate.

Comment: I have checked this bot id(Miss Worksmart) and able to see the responses from bot. This is working fine for me. Please check from your side and let us know still you are seeing any issues with this bot?

Comment: The bot is still not working for me and few other people. Just tested with someone else in the tenant who never used it before and it works for them. The issue only seems to affect some people that have previously used it.

Comment: I found the issue. The bot got stuck in a loop - now solved. Thanks for you help.